# How can I integrate native openCv library for flutter windows application?

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, opencv

Can anyone tell me the steps to integrate native openCV library in the flutter windows application?

I am aware of the process's like(Through dart ffi) -

1. Load the dynamic library
2. LookUp function in the library
3. Than calling the functions.

But I don't know how can I create the dynamic library. What are the steps I have to follow to create dynamic library? What will be my CMakeList.txt file? I don't know anything about creating dynamic library.

Would be much more helpful if I can get an example of how can I create a simple dynamic library with simple function like getting opencv version? I couldn't see much article for flutter windows application.